# How to export dataframe into MIM graphical models

Tags: r, export

I have several dataframe in R format .rds, and I want import them to MIM graphical models.
Is my format dataframe .rds true?
Why MIM can read it?

I have searched, and found that there is a package named "mimR", but it can't be installed,
is that package still available or not?

Comment: Not sure when it was removed but it's not on CRAN. Many other graphical modeling packages are/were available. https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/gR.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure when it was removed but it's not on CRAN. (Last version dated 2012.) Many other graphical modeling packages are/were available. https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/gR.html  ... and .... since the author of that package is also the maintainer of the Task View, I think we can conclude that the package is not "available". Perhaps it's functionality was subsumed in another package.

The package itself is in the CRAN Archives. It is, however, labeled as a "Windows-only package". It is available at https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/mimR/ and do note that you might need proper installation of RTools in order to install from a source package in  `.tar.gz` format. Further investigation: You could unpack the package an pull out useful R code if that code does not depend on compiled .dlls. And looking at the code, there is no compiled code so you can just page through the .R files in the ../R/ directory of the expanded file. After looking at tseveral of the .R files, I could not see a reason that it should be "Windows-only", but I didn't do a complete search.